# Getting a random string within a string

Tags: php

I need to find a random string within a string.

My string looks as follows

{theme}pink{/theme} or {theme}red{/theme}

I need to get the text between the tags, the text may differ after each refresh.

My code looks as follows

```
$str = '{theme}pink{/theme}'; 
preg_match('/{theme}*{\/theme}/',$str,$matches);
```

But no luck with this.

Comment: }* matches the brace zero or more times... you might want to try something like }.*{

Comment: tried that, and it returns {theme}pink{/theme}, I need to get the value pink now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$matches = array();
$str = '{theme}pink{/theme}';
preg_match('/{([^}]+)}([^{]+){\/([^}]+)}/', $str, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

That will dump out all matches of all "tags" you may be looking for. Try it out and look at `$matches` and you'll see what I mean. I'm assuming you're trying to build your own rudimentary template language so this code snippet may be useful to you. If you are, I may suggest looking at something like [Smarty](http://smarty.net/).

In any case, you need parentheses to capture values in regular expressions. There are three captured values above:

```
([^}]+)
```

will capture the value of the opening "tag," which is `theme`. The `[^}]+` means "one or more of any character BUT the `}` character, which makes this non-greedy by default.

```
([^{]+)
```

Will capture the value between the tags. In this case we want to match all characters BUT the `{` character.

```
([^}]+)
```

Will capture the value of the closing tag.

Answer (score 3):

* is only the quantifier, you need to specify what the quantifier is for. You've applied it to }, meaning there can be 0 or more '}' characters. You probably want "any character", represented by a dot.
And maybe you want to capture only the part between the {..} tags with (.*)

```
$str = '{theme}pink{/theme}'; 
preg_match('/{theme}(.*){\/theme}/',$str,$matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Answer (score 2):

`'/{theme}(.*?){\/theme}/'` or even more restrictive `'/{theme}(\w*){\/theme}/'` should do the job

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_match_all('/{theme}(.*?){\/theme}/', $str, $matches);
```

You should use ungreedy matching here. `$matches[1]` will contain the contents of all matched tags as an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('/{theme}([^{]*){\/theme}/',$str,$matches);
```

`[^{]` matches any character except the opening brace to make the regex non-greedy, which is important, if you have more than one tag per string/line